# Save apt- dependencies to text-file

Tags: apt, package-management, bash, scripts, dependencies

I would like to save the list with dependencies for installed programs into a text-file. The reason I would like to do that is for example if I am to install a meta-package, which in turn would rely on several other packages, which are not removed by removing the meta-package alone.

I know that I can do it with:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop | tee log_file.txt
```

But that saves the whole output from the command. I would like to only have a list with the installed package and dependencies so that I can use this command to remove the package and dependencies:

```
 sudo apt remove $(cat log_file.txt)
```

I guess it should be possible, it is just beyond my knowledge of Bash and shell-scripting. So tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `apt-cache` and `awk`

```
apt-cache showpkg kubuntu-desktop | awk '/Dependencies:/,/Provides:/ {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {if(i%3==0) {print $i}}}' | tee log_file.txt
```

*Example (with `ubuntu-desktop`, sorry)*

```
% apt-cache showpkg ubuntu-desktop | awk '/Dependencies:/,/Provides:/ {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {if(i%3==0) {print $i}}}' > out     

% cat out
alsa-base
alsa-utils
anacron
at-spi2-core
baobab
bc
ca-certificates
checkbox-gui
dmz-cursor-theme
doc-base
eog
evince
file-roller
fonts-dejavu-core
fonts-freefont-ttf
foomatic-db-compressed-ppds
gedit
genisoimage
ghostscript-x
gnome-calculator
gnome-font-viewer
gnome-menus
gnome-power-manager
gnome-screenshot
gnome-session-canberra
gnome-system-log
gnome-system-monitor
gstreamer1.0-alsa
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
gucharmap
gvfs-bin
inputattach
language-selector-gnome
libatk-adaptor
libnotify-bin
libpam-systemd
libsasl2-modules
lightdm
memtest86+
nautilus
nautilus-sendto
notify-osd
openprinting-ppds
printer-driver-pnm2ppa
pulseaudio
rfkill
seahorse
software-center
software-properties-gtk
ssh-askpass-gnome
system-config-printer-gnome
ubuntu-artwork
ubuntu-drivers-common
ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
ubuntu-session
ubuntu-settings
ubuntu-sounds
ubuntu-sso-client-qt
unity
unity-control-center
unity-greeter
unity-settings-daemon
unzip
update-manager
update-notifier
wireless-tools
wpasupplicant
xdg-user-dirs
xdg-user-dirs-gtk
xdiagnose
xkb-data
xorg
yelp
zenity
zip
acpi-support
activity-log-manager
aisleriot
app-install-data-partner
apport-gtk
avahi-autoipd
avahi-daemon
bluez
bluez-cups
branding-ubuntu
brasero
brltty
cheese
cups
cups-bsd
cups-client
cups-filters
deja-dup
empathy
example-content
firefox
fonts-droid
fonts-guru
fonts-kacst-one
fonts-khmeros-core
fonts-lao
fonts-liberation
fonts-lklug-sinhala
fonts-nanum
fonts-sil-abyssinica
fonts-sil-padauk
fonts-takao-pgothic
fonts-thai-tlwg
fonts-tibetan-machine
gcc
gnome-accessibility-themes
gnome-bluetooth
gnome-disk-utility
gnome-keyring
gnome-mahjongg
gnome-mines
gnome-orca
gnome-screensaver
gnome-sudoku
gnome-terminal
gnupg-agent
gvfs-fuse
hplip
ibus
ibus-gtk
ibus-gtk3
ibus-table
im-config
kerneloops-daemon
landscape-client-ui-install
laptop-detect
libgail-common
libnss-mdns
libpam-gnome-keyring
libproxy1-plugin-gsettings
libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager
libqt4-sql-sqlite
libreoffice-calc
libreoffice-gnome
libreoffice-impress
libreoffice-math
libreoffice-ogltrans
libreoffice-pdfimport
libreoffice-style-human
libreoffice-writer
libwmf0.2-7-gtk
make
mousetweaks
nautilus-share
network-manager-gnome
network-manager-pptp
network-manager-pptp-gnome
onboard
overlay-scrollbar
pcmciautils
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
policykit-desktop-privileges
printer-driver-brlaser
printer-driver-c2esp
printer-driver-foo2zjs
printer-driver-min12xxw
printer-driver-ptouch
printer-driver-pxljr
printer-driver-sag-gdi
printer-driver-splix
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pulseaudio-module-x11
python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat
qt-at-spi
remmina
rhythmbox
rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune
shotwell
simple-scan
sni-qt
speech-dispatcher
telepathy-idle
thunderbird
thunderbird-gnome-support
totem
transmission-gtk
ttf-ancient-fonts-symbola
ttf-indic-fonts-core
ttf-ubuntu-font-family
ubuntu-docs
unity-webapps-common
usb-creator-gtk
vino
whoopsie
xcursor-themes
xdg-utils
xterm
xul-ext-ubufox
zeitgeist-core
zeitgeist-datahub
```

Comment: Won't the reverse-depends list be constant whereas the actual depends will "depend" on what the OP already has installed on the system because many dependencies are shared between applications and may already be installed or shouldn't be removed?

Comment: @A.B. I think my question was unclear. I have tried to clarify it above. As I understand it, your suggestion regarding aptitude would more or less have the same function apt-get autoremove which removes the dependencies. I'm looking for a script that removes all installed packages that was installed with that particular command/package/meta-package.

Comment: Something like this?